# Displaying custom text with price in short description product WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create an automatic text in the sort description of the WooCommerce products and put the price of the product in this message.

***For example: "buying this product you get 50 points."***

In this example, he earns 50 points because he is in a product that costs $ 50

Here is the code I am using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', function() {
   echo 'Buying this product you get X points';
}, 25 );
```

I put this code in the functions.php, but it only shows the text, I could not put the price of the product too.

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce has a function just for that. You just need to declare it. The function is `get_price_html()` will return the price with the currency format, if you want it without those you can just use the `$product->get_price();` and just have to declare `global $product;` before using it.
Here is the code i used.

```
function PricePoints(){
  global $product;
  echo 'Buying this product you get '.$product->get_price().' points';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','PricePoints',25);
```

This is how it gets displayed in my theme (in your theme will be different)
[image]

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly what I was looking for.

Just one question, would I have to remove the currency symbol? Just leave the numbers?

If so, is it possible to leave them in another format? Only the numbers, without points or commas.

Ex: Buying this product you get 1780 points

Comment: I have modified my original answer adding the function you need for just displaying the number without format. If the answer was helpful, consider marking it as an Answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!